# Get Current position on ZoomStart

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using **leaflet** to display a map.

This is my head code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

and this is my body code :

```
<div id="mapid" style="height: 1000px">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 3
    }).addTo(mymap);

    mymap.on('click', function (e) { alert(e.latlng); });
    mymap.on('zoomstart', function (e) { alert(e.latlng); });
</script>
```

This map has two events as you can see from the code above : on click event and on zoomstart event.

When I click on the map I got the popup alert : **LatLng(51.51600,-1.54213)**.

But when I zoom on the map I got the popup alert : **undefined**.

How can I get the current position on zoomstart Event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Leaflet, the events for map state change do not have a `latlng` property.

Read the documentation, and notice the difference between the `zoomstart`/`zoomend`/etc events...

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-map-state-change-events

...and the events generated by user interaction, such as `click`:

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-interaction-events

Depending on the event type, some information is or is not available. In most cases, events have the information that makes sense for them.

If you want to know the map's center `latlng` when a zoom operation starts, simply use `mymap.getCenter()` inside the event handler.

Comment: mymap.getCenter() worked for me, I wanted to get the current position based on mouse position, theorically it is possible but it is not implemented as a property to use.

Comment: No, you can not assume that the user is using a mouse at all. Think a smartphone, and a zoom operation triggered on a timeout.

Comment: oh you are right, did not think about mobile devices